# Where to find the right replacement of this kind of range hood?

Tags: range-hood

I want to replace a rangehood which seems to be a very old model (As seen in the picture).

[image]

The width is 60cm wide and the height is about 7cm.

The problem is in the Sydney, Australia area, I am unable to find a equvianlent. Most of the them seem to require an exhaust. The model in the picture does not have an exhaust.

[image]

[image]

I would appreciate any pointer to find an equivalent of replacement to this unit in Sydney area.

Comment: Search using ductless.  A fast search found them available in Australia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of them can just recirculate by blocking off the vent access - there's usually a removable plate. 60cm is standard size.
[It has to be said, though, that other than a tiny bit of grease collection, all they become useful for without external venting is as a light. The fan is just a noise, to all intents & purposes].

The trade calls this type a 'visor hood'.

[image] [image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

This is what Amazon UK returns for a search on ["cooker visor hood"](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=Cooker%20visor%20hood&crid=38M399HBLDLUW&sprefix=cooker%20visor%20hood%2Caps%2C67&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)